Does the doctrine of Divine Simplicity imply God needs no explanation?
In his blog here, Edward Feser writes,

But couldn’t a theist hold that while there are no brute facts concerning anything other than God, there are brute facts concerning God himself?  Could he not say that God’s existence is a brute fact, or that God’s having a certain attribute is a brute fact?


Again, not on a classical theist conception of God.  Suppose God is, as Aristotelians hold, pure actuality with no potentiality; or that he is, as Thomists hold, subsistent being itself.  Then he exists of absolute necessity, and thus has his sufficient reason in his own nature, and thus is not a “brute fact.”

He thus argues that God’s existence doesn’t break the principle of sufficient reason since His sufficient reason is in His very own nature. He says that God is thus not a brute fact
Later in the blog he seems to imply that this is because He is not composite (I.e. made of no parts) and says that if He is made of parts, the parts making up the composite would need a reason for how it is that they make up that composite. But since He is made of none, this doesn’t apply. He says,

That entails that he is a mixture of actuality and potentiality, and of an essence together with a distinct “act of existence” (to use the Thomist jargon).  But that in turn entails that he is composite rather than absolutely simple.  And that is incompatible with the classical theist position that divine simplicity is essential to theism, as well as with the de fide teaching of the Catholic Church (declared at the First Vatican Council as well as at the Fourth Lateran Council) that God is simple or non-composite.  Even to say that while God exists necessarily, his having some particular attribute is a “brute fact,” would also conflict with divine simplicity.


If God were composite then it would make sense to ask how it is that his component parts -- act and potency, essence and existence, substance and attributes, or whatever -- happen to be combined together to form the composite.  It would make sense to ask “What caused God?,” in which case we would not really be talking about God anymore, because we would no longer be talking about the ultimate source of things.

So does this mean God can’t be a brute fact? Why does something containing parts need an explanation? What if the parts that make up the composite do so for no further reason?

Stella... how would this blogger guy know whether god was made of parts or not made of parts.  Just how would one go about getting that data?  Can you imagine a way?  Nope.  Therefore... dude is blowin hot air.

@ChrisDegnen The link from your comment is a bit simple. Anselm's attempt to give an ontological proof of God's existence is a better shot, but also without success.

[edited] We have here that "[God] is synonymous with existence itself", so saying "God's existence" is like saying existence's existence, which suggests that the existence of the existence of existence must also exist, etc.  Likewise the reason for the reason for the reason of reason exhibits a similar problem.  And perhaps this is resolved by the PSR only saying that determinate, objective things have determinations (as reasons/causes).

@JoWehler Re. the link – apparently "According to Thomas [Aquinas] the ontological proof is impossible because, starting out from ourselves, we are not in a position to expound the pure concept of God so as to demonstrate from it the necessity of his existence." (Heidegger, The Basic Problems of Phenomenology, page 31).

And for completeness, on page 32 : "The thesis of Kant, whose phenological interpretation we are taking as our theme, is nothing but the fundamental denial of the possibility of the assertion laid down in the minor premise of the ontological proof. Kant's thesis that being or existence is not a real predicate does not assert merely that existence cannot belong to the concept of the most perfect being or that we cannot know it to belong to that concept (Thomas). It goes further. It says, fundamentally, that something like existence does not belong to the determinateness of a concept at all."

People do seem to try very hard to define God into existence in ways that don't sound like... defining God into existence. Asserting that God is a brute fact or asserting that God is simple are just assertions (or definitions) that we have no reason to accept to be the case, and which tell us basically nothing about the truth of whether we'll be tortured for all eternity if we don't accept a human sacrifice (or whatever whichever religion says).

God isn't a fact. There is no definite proof of existence or non-existence so God can't be a brute fact. There are, however, two brute facts about God: God exists and God doesn't exist. These two brute facts carry equal weight.

I think the logic goes as follows...

Keep the PSR
Define God in such a way that God's existence is a sufficient reason for itself, meaning God doesn't have to be a brute fact, meaning God has to have been God forever.
If you suppose God has parts, then you start to undermine 2), because you then raise the question of what was the cause of the parts and what caused the parts to come together to be God etc etc. Much easier to avoid all that inconvenience by assuming God is partless.


+1 This ^^. Basically IF you want to satisfy the PSR and have god be self-explanatory, then you must have him be simple.
Of course, maybe god does have parts and therefore is contingent on a more basic thing .. not God but simply "pure existence" whose essence implies existence trivially.
Existence must exist, necessarily.

@Annika Re. "Existence must exist" - Note iv of H. 4 Being & Time has an interesting quote from Pascal: "We cannot undertake to define being without falling into this absurdity: because we cannot define a word without starting with it, it is either expressed or implied. Therefore, to define being, one would have to say it is, and thus use the word defined in its definition."

'On ne peut entreprendre de définir l'être sans tomber dans cette absurdité: car on ne peut définir un mot sans commencer par celui-ci, c'est, soit qu'on l'exprime ou qu'on le sous-entende. Done pour définir l'être, il faudrait dire c'est, et ainsi employer le mot défini dans sa définition.' - Pensées et Opuscules p. 169.

Can something that cannot be defined be said to exist? "Indeed, "being" cannot be understood as a being." [GA 2] – so it appears not, and we escape the absurdity of the existence of the existence of existence's existence, etc.  On first blush it does seem that existence must exist but just a few steps down the rabbit hole and it's not apparent anymore.

I take the term “brute fact” to mean a fact that cannot be explained in terms of a deeper, more fundamental fact.
The blog linked in the OP’s question starts with

"Could he [the theist] not say that God’s existence is a brute fact, or that God’s having a certain attribute is a brute fact?"

Hence the argumentation in the blog is circular: First one has to agree that the existence of God is a fact at all. Of course the theist has to argue that his/her concept of God is not an empty concept, without a referent.

+1 A fact is something known to be true so God is not a fact since there is no proof either way so God cant be a brute fact. This leaves two brute facts about God: God exists and God doesn't exist. These brute facts are equal.
